# iOS UITableView cells loading even if off screen

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios-autolayout

What would be possible issues having a UITableView load all of it's cells even though most are off screen?

The custom cells are using Auto-Layout as well as the entire screen that the table view is in.

This is happening in ios versions 8, 7, 6

Comment: Please try to explain more clearly.

Comment: A UITableView reuses table view cells, so it won't create more than one offscreen cell for each identifier.

Comment: Are you saying that your cells currently are loading if they're off the screen? Or are you saying you want them to?

Comment: Turns out that if you put a Table View under a Scroll View, this is what will happen.  It will "call for" all cells in the Table View.  So, need to take it out of the scroll view and do the UI somehow else.

Comment: begs the question, why do you have a table view under a scroll view ?

Comment: The combo of a scroll+clipping view should do this correctly so only some small portion of off-screen cells are rendered (to improve scrolling responsiveness)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not put table view under a scroll view and / or turn off the scrolling for the table view.